# How do you add an onchange event handler in Elm?

Tags: event-handling, onchange, elm

I need to add an `onchange` event handler in an input element in my Elm project but it does not seem to be available.
For example, if I want to add and `onclick` event handler, I can use the below code:

```
input [ onClick   { desc = "ClickFunction", info = model.name } ] []
```

But when I try to do the below for `onchange`, it does not work:

```
input [ onChange   { desc = "ChangeFunction", info = model.name } ] []
```

This is the error message I get:

```
NAMING ERROR - I cannot find a `onChange` variable:
These names seem close though:
31|                     [ onChange   { desc = "ChangeFunction", info = model.name ] []
                                                                                                    #^^^^^^^^#
    #onCheck#
    #srclang#
    #enctype#
    #lang#
```

So how do I implement the `onchange` event handler?

Answer (score 3):

Typically the `input` event is a better choice than the `change` event, which is why it isn't included in the default set of event handlers. However, if you have a case where you don't want a message in Elm until the change is committed, you have a couple of options.

You maybe want to use [`Html.Events.Extra.onChange`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra/latest/Html-Events-Extra#onChange) from the [elm-community/html-extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/html-extra/latest) package.

You can also use [`Html.Events.on`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/latest/Html-Events#on) to create a custom handler. For example,

```
onChange : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onChange tagger =
    on "change" (targetValue |> Json.Decode.map tagger)
```

See [an Ellie app](https://ellie-app.com/hRjTbNKT38ka1) that demonstrates this example. Note that you can change `onChange` to `onInput` in this example and it works just the same.